# Switching between fragments with onClickListener in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently working on an app that deals with fragments. In one of my fragments, I need to have an `OnClickListener` that will inflate another fragment whenever it is clicked. My main activity is the one that generally does the switching between fragments, so is there a way to get my app to replace my current fragment with the one I want? This is how I'm switching between fragments currently:

```
fragmentClass = home_fragment.class;
try {
    fragment = (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I found somebody else having this same issue and they just recreated the fragmentManager. Is this a good method of doing this? I feel like the app would eventually become confused when switching between fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my fragment, I found out a way to call a method from the previous activity:

```
((Home)getActivity()).ChangeFragment(profile_fragment.class,user);
```

`ChangeFragment` is the method that changes the fragment for me. So I just pass in the fragment class that I want to switch to and voila! It works!

Answer (score 2):

i believe you can achieve this by defining an interface on fragment and implement it on activity, let the fragment onClick method fires the listener implemented by activity to change the fragment. this must be like clicking on a list item on item fragment and alert activity to replace item fragment with the details fragment to show details about item selected.

check this for more implementation details:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Although this seems like it could work, it was a bit too complex for my needs. I found another way of doing this, thank you though!